# propositional logic truth values in compound biconditionals

Tags: logic

I need to know the truth value of the following proposition, given that $A$ and $B$ are true and $X$ and $Y$ are false:

$$[A\rightarrow\neg(B \wedge Y)]\leftrightarrow[B\rightarrow(X \wedge \neg A)]$$

Comment: What's "<>"?${}$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I think it means "iff" or equivalence.

Comment: Double Arrow, I believe.

Comment: What do you suggest its truth value to be?

Comment: I'm thinking that it must be false, the falsehood of B is predicated upon the truth of A while we are being told that both are true. Am I on to something, or just confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's begin with the left side of the biconditional. Since B is true and Y is false $B \wedge Y$ is false, and therefore $\neg(B\wedge Y)$ is true. Since $A$ is true, the LHS is $True \rightarrow True$, which is true.

Now, the right side of the biconditional. Since $X$ is false and $A$ is true, $X\wedge \neg A$ is false. B is true, and therefore, $B\rightarrow (X\wedge\neg A)$ is $True \rightarrow False$, which is false – indeed $T \rightarrow F$ is the only way for a conditional statement to be false.

So, the left hand side is true, and the right hand side is false. But a biconditional is true only when we are looking at *equal* truth values. That is, $True \leftrightarrow False$ is false, and so the whole statement is false.

The easiest approach for such problems is always to break them down into smaller easier problems, looking at the more simple logical structures first (e.g., disjunctions and conjunctions) and moving on up to conditionals and biconditionals from there.